# What is it called when I a person transfers his angry towards another person, instead of the person that cause and anger?

Tags: bias

My significant other has described to me how he has always been the good child who received 4.0 in school, went to the marines was honorably discharged and always do things for his family. He says some of his family members have taken things from him without his permission while he was overseas and not return or replace them.  When he tries to address them no one wants to address the issue, so when he gets angry they make him feel as if he doesn't have a right to his anger.  Now that we are together I feel he transfers these angry feelings towards me.  I try to express that I understand his anger and try not to take anything from him without his permission or I even try to replace things if I have done something to his possessions.

Comment: Actually, this can be an example of displacement (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_(psychology)#Aggression) or projection (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychological_projection#Practical_examples).  Both apply to transferring anger (eg, bullying, abuse, etc) - this ambiguity is part of the problem with psychoanalytic theories, so use this only as a label, not as an explanation...  Anyways, this forum is not a good place to ask about personal issues, so I'd rather see this question closed.